# Get text starting from scrolled position

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get text starting from scrolled position text area?

I have a textarea with vertical scroll-bar. I want to get the text starting from the scrolled position. How can I get it?

```
var $textArea = $('textarea');
$('#btn').click(function(){
    var top = textArea.scrollTop();
});
```

Comment: Code? And shouldn't this be a JavaScript question and not a Java question?

Answer (score 0):

You could split the lines, and them get them based on the height you have declared on them.

```js
var $textArea = $('textarea');
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var top = $textArea.scrollTop();
  var lines = $textArea.val().split('\n');

  var n = Math.floor(top / 20)
  var currentline = lines[n];
  var textScroll = ""
  for (i = n; i < (lines.length); i++) {
    textScroll += lines[i]+"\n"
  }
  alert(textScroll)
});
```

```css
textarea {
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows=5>1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13</textarea>

<button id="btn">
  CLICK
</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xx8s6bmw/

Comment: It will not work when the single line width is greater than the textarea width.

Comment: If you are not using a monospace font, its gonna be really complex to calculate it them, i think it would be easier to implement a custom textarea since there are no straighforward way of doing what you want.